# Load and display HTML file from assets in TextView

Tags: android, textview

I need to display htlm file in textview, now I'm writing the code in string.xml file and load from there, but i would a more clean code.
How can I load and display it?
I found this guide
http://adilatwork.blogspot.it/2013/03/android-load-and-show-html-from-file.html
But seems not working

Comment: define `not working`.

Comment: HTML support in TextViews is much **LIMITED**. Only some tags are supported. You'd better use a `WebView`, which is a specialized control for HTML...

Comment: IOUtils cannot be resolved

Comment: first of all why you are using .xml? if you want lo load html file create it in assets folder and then use it. IOUtils which used in the link comes from apache jar. You will get jar form here https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi

Answer (score 1):

**This will help**

> **Prerequicities apache commons jar file**
>
> Download apache common jar from [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi)
>
> OR
>
> use gradle i.e. put dependency in your build.gradle
>
> compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'

**Create html file into your assets folder lets say my_file.html**

> Put below code in my_file.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <h1>This is my html from file</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

**Now create you activity and put TextView in xml of that activity**

> set id myTextView to the TextVeiw in activities xml file.
>
> now in your onCreate method of after setContentView call use above link code

```
  try
  {
    //Note here I gave file name with "file:///android_asset/" to get it from assets
    InputStream inputStream = getResources().getAssets().open("file:///android_asset/myFile.html");

    String html = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);

    myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(html));
  }
  catch (IOException exception)
  {
    myTextView.setText("Failed loading html.");
  }
```

> **IMPORTANT NOTE :** Android TextView has limited support i.e. it only works for basic html tags. If you want more supports WebView is the way.

Comment: IOUtils is deprecated, as is Html.fromHtml